# MS Graph Excel API - call to /workbook/createSession causes workbook to be read-only in Excel client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A call made to createSession like below makes the workbook read-only in the Excel client:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<workbookid>/workbook/createSession
```

Is this expected behavior? It seems to last for about 15 minutes and then the workbook can be edited again in the Excel client.

Is there a way to explicitly end the session via code, eg. REST API, and release the read-only lock?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

The `closeSession` action should release the session and allow editing.

However, I'm seeing an error with `closeSession` API. This may be temporary issue.. We'll follow-up once it it resolved.

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/sample.xlsx:/workbook/closeSession`